# KmlLayer getDefaultViewport() Undefined- Google Maps

Tags: javascript, maps

Thanks for your times, i wish i will be clear enough to talk about my small issue.
I woud like to use a variable "coor" like this:

```
var coor = kml.getDefaultViewport().getCenter();
```

and use this variable to a new MARKER Position.
The problem is: javaScript returns Undefined.

This is my code:

```
    function initialisation(){
    var centreCarte = new google.maps.LatLng(liste[0][2], liste[0][3]);
    var optionsCarte = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: centreCarte,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP}                           
    var maCarte = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("EmplacementDeMaCarte"), optionsCarte);

    var i=0,li=liste.length;
    while(i<li){
    var kml = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://myestory.fr/kml/'+liste[i]                [0].toString()+'.kml',
                        {
                        'preserveViewport': true,
                        'map': maCarte
                        });

    var coor = kml.getDefaultViewport().getCenter();

    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(coor),
    map: maCarte,
    ... //other options of MarkerWithLabel
    });
    i++;}
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialisation);

    </script>
</head>
```

So do you know why variable "coor" doesn't take any values?
And is there any other solutions?

Thanks!!

Cz

Answer (score 3):

A guy give me some usefull details concerning my problem. In fact, i have to use a listener inside the loop, like this:

```
function initialisation(){
    //affectation du résultat de la requète SQL et création des variables
var liste = [<?php echo $liste;?>];
var centreCarte = new google.maps.LatLng(liste[0][2], liste[0][3]);
var optionsCarte = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: centreCarte,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP}

var maCarte = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("EmplacementDeMaCarte"), optionsCarte);

//boucle permettant l'affichage des fichiers KML et la création des MARKER
//en fonction de la liste obtenue lors de la requète SQL
var i=0,li=liste.length;
while(i<li){
    var kml = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://site.fr/kml/'+liste[i][0].toString()+'.kml', {
            'preserveViewport': true,
            'map': maCarte,
            'valeuri': i
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(kml, "defaultviewport_changed", 
        function() {
            var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                    'position': this.getDefaultViewport().getCenter(),
                    'map': this.getMap(),
                    'draggable': true,
                    'raiseOnDrag': false,
                    'icon': 'http://site.fr/icon/noicon.png',
                    'labelContent': liste[this.valeuri][1],
                    'labelAnchor': new google.maps.Point(27, 12),
                    'labelClass': "labels",
                    'labelStyle': {opacity: 1}  
            });
        });
    i++;}
}
```

So now, i can display MARKER with label only (noicon.png is 1px*1px image) in the center of all KML that have been loaded in the loop.

++

Cz